# Center ajax loader

Tags: css

I am trying to center the ajax loader. But no luck. Appreciate assistance. Below is the code

```
div.amshopby-overlay {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 555;
}
div.amshopby-overlay img {
    top: 100px;
    left: 45%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

div.amshopby-overlay div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background:  url('../images/amshopby-overlay.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do trick for you

```
div.amshopby-overlay div {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 130px;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        width: 130px;
        z-index: 1000;
        background:  url('../images/amshopby-overlay.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    }
```